# Sharepoint - User getting Access Denied error although has correct permissions

Tags: wss

I have a group of users are getting an error 'Access Denied' on a particular page.

I've checked permissions for that page and they have contribute rights - they also have contribute rights in the parent page.

But for some reason I can't work out why they get an access denied error?

Comment: What is on the offending page?  Any custom code or web parts?  Sometimes when a custom web part has an exception it bubbles up as an access denied error to the end user.

Answer (score 3):

It can be different things.

- Maybe an image on the page that users have no access to?
- Maybe a web part pointing to a list that users have no access to?

To help more you must provide information on what's on the page also.

To error search yourself you can add ?contents=1 to the url and then manually shut down all web parts on the page. A good trick when error searching is to close down one by one and see when it starts to work.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the user is not fully connected to the sitecollection.

Remove the user from the site info users list (sitecollection url/_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0). 
Through this action the user will lose all his rights in the sitecollection. The next step is reassign the user with rights to the sitecollection.
Now the user will have acces.